# Xamarin Android binding vs. pure C# library performance

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

How much faster pure C# code against code written on Java and binded to C# for using with Xamarin?

For example.
Pure C# code:

```
int Foo (int a, int b) 
{
     return a + b;
}
```

Versus same code on Java binded to C#?

More complex example - performance of C# realization of WebSockets vs. Java native and binded to C#:
https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp vs. https://github.com/NVentimiglia/Websockets.PCL

Comment: How about benchmarking it? Make a binding library that does the same and see how much overhead JNI has.